# Selecting all info from nodes with the same name

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, nodes

I'm a total newbie when it comes to xml stuff.

So far I have this piece of xml that I want to extract info from, but all the node names are the same (so it just grabs one of them, unless stated otherwise).

It looks something like this:

```
<DocumentElement>
  <Screening>
  <ScreeningID>2</ScreeningID>
  <ScreeningDate>2011-09-13T00:00:00-04:00</ScreeningDate>
  <ScreeningResult>1</ScreeningResult>
  <ScreeningResultText>Negative</ScreeningResultText>
  <TextResult>0</TextResult>
  <TextResultText>Not Tested</TextResultText>
  <PageNumber>0</PageNumber>
  <AddedDate>2015-05-03T16:06:41.71774-04:00</AddedDate>
  <UpdateDate>2015-05-03T16:06:41.71774-04:00</UpdateDate>
</Screening>
<Screening>
  <ScreeningID>3</ScreeningID>
  <ScreeningDate>2011-09-13T00:00:00-04:00</ScreeningDate>
  <ScreeningResult>1</ScreeningResult>
  <ScreeningResultText>Negative</ScreeningResultText>
  <TextResult>1</TextResult>
  <TextResultText>Negative</TextResultText>
  <PageNumber>9</PageNumber>
  <AddedDate>2015-05-03T16:25:21.2904988-04:00</AddedDate>
  <UpdateDate>2015-05-03T16:25:21.2904988-04:00</UpdateDate>
</Screening>
```

And I'm currently using this kind of snippet to extract info from the TextResult area

```
Select 
answer.value('(/DocumentElement/Screening/TextResult)[1]','int')
From 
Answers
```

However, that only grabs the first bit of info, I know that if I write something like this, it'll get me the second bit of info but on another column: `answer.value('(/DocumentElement/Screening[2]/textResult)[1]','int')`

I have two issues with this: 1. There isn't necessarily going to be only 2 nodes with the same name - it could go on infinitely.  And 2. I would like all the info to be gathered into only one column.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you saying you want to loop through it and get all `textResult` items?  or nodes with a specific value?

Comment: You have an array of Screening[].  So DocumentElement is the DataBase.  Screening is a Table in the DataBase.  The tags under Sreening are the fields(columns) in the Table like ScreeningID, ScreeningDate, ScreeningResult, ....  To get the array you would need to query for /DocumentElement/Screening to get the NodeList.

Comment: 1: Can you post your full code; 2: What RDBMS are you using?  They all have different limitations and syntax for XQuery

Comment: I want to capture all textresults in all areas.  So in this case it would capture 0 & 1

Comment: Also added in code snippet - I just want to capture the testResults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
SELECT 
    X.value('.','int') as 'TextResult'
FROM Answers as 'a'
     CROSS APPLY a.answer.nodes('/DocumentElement/Screening/TextResult') as answers(X)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb/5580)**

Answer (score 0):

I understand your meaning is: get all TextResult in your xml document. If so, you can try this:

```js
string xml = @"<DocumentElement>
                              <Screening>
                              <ScreeningID>2</ScreeningID>
                              <ScreeningDate>2011-09-13T00:00:00-04:00</ScreeningDate>
                              <ScreeningResult>1</ScreeningResult>
                              <ScreeningResultText>Negative</ScreeningResultText>
                              <TextResult>0</TextResult>
                              <TextResultText>Not Tested</TextResultText>
                              <PageNumber>0</PageNumber>
                              <AddedDate>2015-05-03T16:06:41.71774-04:00</AddedDate>
                              <UpdateDate>2015-05-03T16:06:41.71774-04:00</UpdateDate>
                            </Screening>
                            <Screening>
                              <ScreeningID>3</ScreeningID>
                              <ScreeningDate>2011-09-13T00:00:00-04:00</ScreeningDate>
                              <ScreeningResult>1</ScreeningResult>
                              <ScreeningResultText>Negative</ScreeningResultText>
                              <TextResult>1</TextResult>
                              <TextResultText>Negative</TextResultText>
                              <PageNumber>9</PageNumber>
                              <AddedDate>2015-05-03T16:25:21.2904988-04:00</AddedDate>
                              <UpdateDate>2015-05-03T16:25:21.2904988-04:00</UpdateDate>
                            </Screening>
                        </DocumentElement>";
            XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse(xml);
            IEnumerable<XElement> textResultList = from c in xmlTree.Descendants("TextResult")
                                          select c;
            foreach (var item in textResultList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            }

            Console.Read();
```

I hope this help

Comment: Notice that the question has tag `SQL` and no `C#` tag

Comment: @har07 But I think above question don't relate to SQL, because the author didn't talk about SQL.

Comment: Sample code he posted is valid SQL server syntax for querying XML column `Select answer.value(....) From Answers`. For ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx